# ARSCNView CGAffineTransform error in Ipad Portrait

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, cgaffinetransform

I found a very strange error when I try to flip an ARSCNView vertically on an iPad, what I need to do suppose to be:

```
sceneView.transform = sceneView.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: -1)
```

which should flip the ARSCNView vertically. **It rotates 90 degrees instead of flipping.**  Strangely the following gives the same result:

```
sceneView.transform = sceneView.transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
```

**Scale X and Y should not rotate the View.**

Where this problem happens:
Ipad pro 12.9 2019, iOS 14.0.1, in portrait mode

What else that I tried:
Everything works on iPhone.

The following works but not what I need

```
sceneView.transform = sceneView.transform.rotated(by: .pi)
```

3. on the same device landscape works in both directions. The error only occurs when portrait or portrait upsidedown.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get around?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
sceneView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
```

because `scaledBy` scales off the existing transform, which might not be `.identity`.

But you might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56125537/14351818) too.

Comment: This gives the same result for me I check it gives the same transform matrix (a=-1, b=0, c=0, d = 1) and for some reason, the view is rotated 90 degrees instead of flipping. The other post you mentioned is very interested I will check. Thanks!