# How to stop Swift ARKit app from reverting SCN Technique, and world tracking issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, scntechnique

I am making an ARKit swift app, and have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56109271/arkit-mirror-flip-camera-layer) post on how to apply a mirroring effect to the camera feed. However, I've run into a couple problems. First, the mirroring effect stops after a while. This often happens when the images I am searching for come into the frame, but also happens when looking at something totally unrelated. The camera simply reverts back to the default, unmirrored view, and does not go back to the SCNTechnique mirrored view.

I have been able to conclude that this is not happening when the anchors are placed in the world, since the code is not executing those lines when the mirroring effect reverts back. Is there a way to stop this from happening and make sure the mirroring SCNTechnique remains? I am unsure if this is simply a hardware limitation of the iPhone 11 that the app is running on, or if there is an issue with the code.

Also, whenever the image reverts from the mirrored effect to the default camera feed, the world tracking is severely screwed up. The coordinate axes that are placed in the view essentially just move around with the camera, and do not seem to be attached to any specific place. Is this related to the above issue, or would this be a separate problem with the code or implementation?