# ARView counterpart to SCNView's SCNTechnique?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, metal, realitykit

I have made project with ARKit that uses metal shaders to perform a mirroring effect, and this is assigned by using `sceneView.technique`. I am trying to figure out if it would be possible to transition the project over to using RealityKit instead, but cannot find any similar trait of the `ARView` used by RealityKit. Is there anything in RealityKit similar to `sceneView.technique` that would allow me to simply assign the metal shaders as I do right now, or would I have to rework how the metal shaders are interacting with the view?

My current implementation is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56109271/arkit-mirror-flip-camera-layer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About ARView mirroring

The simplest way to mirror `ARView` in RealityKit 2.0 is to use a `CGAffineTransform` 3x3 matrix.

```
 ┌             ┐
 |  a   b   0  |
 |  c   d   0  |
 |  tx  ty  1  |
 └             ┘
```

We need to reflect a scene (including video) horizontally, so we have to use `-1` multiplier for xScale:

```
 ┌             ┐
 | -1   0   0  |
 |  0   1   0  |
 |  0   0   1  |
 └             ┘
```

Here's the code:

```
arView.transform = .init(a: -1, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1, tx: 0, ty: 0)
```

### About Metal shaders

In RealityKit 2.0 only [CustomMaterial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/modifying_realitykit_rendering_using_custom_materials) allows you implement Metal's vertex and fragment shaders. So, you can use a vertex shader for many interesting effects, including flipping a model across X axis.

`.swift file`:

```
import Metal
import RealityKit

let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    
guard let defaultLibrary = device!.makeDefaultLibrary()
else { return }
    
let shader = CustomMaterial.SurfaceShader(named: "basicShader",
                                             in: defaultLibrary)
    
let modifier = CustomMaterial.GeometryModifier(named: "basicModifier",
                                                  in: defaultLibrary)
    
box.model?.materials[0] = try! CustomMaterial(surfaceShader: shader, 
                                           geometryModifier: modifier, 
                                              lightingModel: .lit)
```

`.metal file`:

```cpp
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <RealityKit/RealityKit.h>

using namespace metal;
using namespace realitykit;

[[visible]]
void basicShader(realitykit::surface_parameters shader)
{
    surface::surface_properties sf = shader.surface();
    
    sf.set_base_color( half3(1.0f, 0.7f ,0.0f) );
};

[[visible]]
void basicModifier(realitykit::geometry_parameters modifier)
{
    float3 pose = modifier.geometry().model_position();

    // your code...
};
```

However, a counterpart of SCNTechnique for RealityKit view isn't "baked" yet...

Comment: Just to clarify, is this for for mirroring the camera feed itself or for making a mirrored material that would be applied to virtual content? I am trying to mirror the whole camera feed, apologies if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I tried putting in `arView.transform = .init(a: -1, b: 0, c: 0, d: 1, tx: 0, ty: 0)` immediately after the initialization of the ARView via `var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)` and got a whole slew of errors. It's saying "consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'", and appears to think that the `arView.transform` line is trying to declare a function. Is there a different initializer I need to use for the CGAffineTransform, or a different way to apply it to the `arView`?

Comment: It 100% works fine – I applied it many times.

Comment: Realized I just needed to move the transform statement into my makeUIView function instead of having it in the ARViewContainer struct. Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use RealityKit 2's PostProcessing API which should make this desired effect pretty easy to implement.

For example you could apply a Core Image Filter or Metal kernel functions to your rendered scene. Somewhat similar to SCNTechnique.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/implementing_special_rendering_effects_with_realitykit_postprocessing?changes=l_6&language=objc